# Write fixtures with counter_cache columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, fixtures, counter-cache

Write fixtures that have counter_cache columns is tedious and complicated, I tried use method reset_counters in test_helper.rb but it didn't work. Same way to put it working ?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What's the expected output? What have you tried?

Comment: If you need write fixtures with counter_cache columns you need write manually... I tried Post.find_each { |post| Post.reset_counters(post.id, :comments, :shares, :likes, :quotes) } to reset counters but it did'nt worked. If i put it inside a setup method.. it works.. but it is executed before every test

Answer (score 2):

I solved that problem using a monkey path to disable counter_cache on test enviroment.

config/environments/test.rb

```
module ActiveRecord::Associations
    class HasManyAssociation
        def has_cached_counter?(reflection = reflection())
            false
        end
    end
end
```